# How to efficiently implement infinity and minus infinity supporting arithmetic in C++?

Tags: c++, math

The trivial solution would be:

```
class Number
{
public: 
    bool isFinite();
    bool isPositive();
    double value();

    ...

private:
    double value_;
    bool isFinite_;
    bool isPositive_;

    ...
};
```

The thing that worries me is efficiency:

From Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs (3rd Edition) by Scott Meyers:

> Even when small objects have inexpensive copy constructors, there can
>   be performance issues. Some compilers treat built-in and user-defined
>   types differently, even if they have the same underlying
>   representation. For example, some compilers refuse to put objects
>   consisting of only a double into a register, even though they happily
>   place naked doubles there on a regular basis. When that kind of thing
>   happens, you can be better off passing such objects by reference,
>   because compilers will certainly put pointers (the implementation of
>   references) into registers.

Is there a way to bypass the efficiency problem? For example a library that uses some assembly language magic?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the assembly to see if your compiler is generating the brain-dead code that you're mentioning?

Comment: I'm curious to hear, after you've solved the performance issue, what your arithmetic operations do when infinities are the operands!

Comment: I am a beginner in C++ and I do not know nearly anything about assembly language. Such things are beyond my current abilities. I was just hoping for a well known solution.

Comment: @cheeken Some operations are well defined, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line, some will return NaN, or throw an exception. Such arithmetic is implemented for example in Mathematica

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Indeed, for a subset of the operations, "infinity operantions" can be deterministic.  But many of them are not, and sets of calculations involving them would seem to quickly transform into pools of `NaN`.  Which, to me, begs the question: is this the right approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is very little reason to implement a Number class for a double.  The double format already implement Infinity, NaN, and signage as part of the raw basic double type.

Second, you should write your code first aiming for correctness, and then try to optimize later, at which time you can look at factor out specific data structure and rewrite code and algos.

Modern day compilers are typically very efficient in writing good code, and typically does a way better job than most human programmers does.

Comment: all true; but when you know upfront that the program must scale well (e.g. a multi channel sound analysis package), you better be aware of potential bottlenecks.

Comment: @xtofl -- then I would suggest programming using #define MACOS and template classes only, and avoid any datastructures which cannot be unrolled by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you Soren! I never realized this. It seems to work as expected with various elementary mathematical functions. But is this standard C++ or just something the creators of gcc compiler threw in as a bonus?

Answer (score 2):

For your *specific* example, I would just use doubles as they are rather than in a class. They're well adapted and defined for handling infinities.

In a more general sense, you should use the trivial solution and only worry about performance when (or, more likely, if) it becomes a problem.

That means code it up and test it in many of the scenarios you're going to use it for.

If it still performs within the bounds of your performance requirements, don't worry about trying to optimise it. And you should *have* some performance requirements slightly more specific that "I want it to run a s fast as possible" :-)

Remember that efficiency *doesn't* always mean "as fast as possible, no matter the cost". It means achieving your goals without necessarily sacrificing other things (like readability or maintainability).

If you take an complete operation that makes the user wait 0.1 seconds and optimise it to the point where it's ten times faster, the user won't notice that at all (I say "complete" because obviously, the user *would* notice a difference if it was done ten thousand times without some sort of interim result).

And remember, *measure, don't guess!*